# Char matrix always prints the last element

Tags: c

I want to write a simple C program that would read a sequence of strings from console into a char[] array, I am not so familiar with the language but what I came up with is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
  const int N = 2;
  char *matrix[N][N];
  char str[50];

   printf("Provide the strings: \n"); // one, two, three, four
   for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
      scanf("%s",str);
      matrix[i][j] = str;
     }
   }

   printf("----> %s", matrix[0][0]); // will print "four"

   return 0;
}
```

And I provide the following strings: `one, two, three, four`.

Now, I want to access the elements in the array, but upon running a loop on the matrix `matrix[i][j]` I found out that all the elements refer to the last introduced element: `four`.

Can somebody explain why this is so? 
And as a follow up question, what would be a more idiomatic way to read and print the elements of a char array?

Comment: Your `printf` is outside the double-nested for-loop.

Comment: `matrix[i][j] = str` is not a string copy. It just points to the same buffer all the time. One option is to make a copy of the string: `matrix[i][j] = strdup(str)`. Don't forget to `free` each of those strings.

Comment: Your matrix stores pointers to the char. Basically, you store all the time the game pointer while modifying its content reach time. At the end of the day you see the last content in all elements. Apparently you need to dynamically allocate memory for each of matrix elements

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica yes, this is fine. At that point I just want to print the first element in the array, so the element located at `[0,0]`, which should be `one`, but at console it always prints `four` which is always the last element. (the printing part where I iterate over the whole array I ommited).

Comment: `the first element in the array` the first element of the array __will point to__ the same string `str`. The same as all the other array elements, they are pointers. All elements will point to the same string. After the loop `str` will contain the last read string.

Comment: You can do it while the loop is running. Furthermore, you need to use char[][] as an array of strings.

Comment: Thank you guys, I definetly missed the concept of pointers in school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matrix[i][j] = str;
```

That is not a string copy. It just points each of the `matrix` entries to the same `str` buffer. That `str` buffer is overwritten on each iteration of the loop. So the result is that all the `matrix` elements point to the same buffer with the contents of the last `scanf`.

One option to resolve this is to make a copy of the string.

```
matrix[i][j] = strdup(str);
```

Don't forget to do error checking to ensure the dynamic allocation in `strdup` succeeded and also `free` the buffers when no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

`str` on its own is a pointer to 50 bytes of memory. When you assign `matrix[i,j] = str`, you're saying that each pointer in your matrix should point to the same location as `str`. Whatever text is currently located at `str` will also be located at all indices of `matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you need to copy the strings instead of assigning the pointer values. An easier way would be to statically allocate the strings and use that memory instead of the redundant `str` string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  const int N = 2;
  char matrix[N][N][50];

   printf("Provide the strings: \n"); // one, two, three, four
   for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
     for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
      scanf("%s", matrix[i][j]);
     }
   }

   printf("----> %s", matrix[0][0]); // will print "one"

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you are going to have static memory for `matrix` then may as well use that directly in the `scanf` rather than having another inefficient copy operation.

Comment: True, I just wanted to show what needs to be replaced. I will edit my code to use the memory directly.